# Batching model created with ModelBuilder in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, batch, error-000865

I created a simple model that selects iteratively elements from a point dataset and calculates a cost distance raster for each of these points.  It works fine when I run it for just one dataset, but when I try to batch it get the following error.

> ERROR 000865: Input raster or feature source data: I_atlanta_OBJECTID does not exist.
>
> ERROR 000581: Invalid parameters.
> Failed to execute (Cost Distance).

Here a link to a snapshot of the model
http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/7432/modelmultidist.png